# How to use git/version control with Unity

Tags: git, version-control, unity-game-engine

What is the proper use of Unity and git?

If I push the changes I made to the scenes and project, and then the other team member pull those changes, they can't properly merge the changes since the scene is a binary file.

So how can we develop on unity and use a version control as a team?

I'm on Unity 5.6.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force Unity to serialise assets and scenes as YAML text based files, this should resolve your merge issues with Git. This setting can be found under the **Edit** > **Project Settings** > **Editor** menu. You then set the "Asset Serialization" setting to **Force Text**, this will allow you to merge scenes using Unity's [YAMLMerge](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SmartMerge.html).

[image: Asset Serialization]

Be warned, depending on the project size when changing this setting re-importing everything can take hours, and it has to be done on every client. There are other additional measures you can take to improve your workflow with Unity and Git, I'd recommend looking at [this excellent post](http://www.deadlyfingers.net/gamedev/unity3d/unity-git/) by David Douglas which goes into much more depth and teaches some of the ways you can all work on the same scene and merge your changes once you're all at your milestones.

There's also [this good Unity Answers post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/222281/asset-serialization-mixed-vs-force-text.html) that talks about the Pros and Cons of different asset serialisation methods that you might want to take a look at before committing to any of them.

Comment: Do you happen to have a guide that actually works on how to set up YAML merge with an external merge tool?

Comment: Have you already looked at the official documentation page for Smart Merge that I linked in the answer? Notably the part about mergespecfile.txt 

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SmartMerge.html

Comment: This is quite a good guide for setting it up as well, it talks about custom merge tools right at the beginning.

https://gist.github.com/Ikalou/197c414d62f45a1193fd

Comment: What's in the official docs don't work.

Comment: I need more information, please can I have a look at your mergespecfile?

Comment: I think I got it to work with Kdiff like they showed in the second link. Thanks.